# osx server files keep locking (read only)

Tags: mac-osx-server

We are a web design company who develop off files stored on a osx leopard server. The issue is that when a developer creates files using textmate in a folder for a new website, when another developer using dreamweaver goes to open and edit these files they are readonly and visa versa.

The only way it seems to get round this is to chmod the files before opening them to 777. Unfortunately when these are uploaded the permissions are maintained, creating potential security risks for our web applications.

Any ideas on how to stop this file locking occuring? Note the files are *not* already open in either application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all your developers are in the same group, so you can set files to 664 (775 for dirs). This is safer than chmodding to 666 or 777 as long as the group the webserver is running doesn't have the same groupid.

Comment: we realised one developer (who first started work on the site) was connecting to the mount/server using guest rather the correct login, thus creating all these permission issues. This is now resolved thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change your umask. I'm not sure if it affects network mounts.
Edit the file: /etc/launchd-user.conf
add a single line:
umask 002

if it doesn't work, how are the clients mounting the share (AFP, SMB, NFS?) you could update the configs of the sharing methods to force specific permissions being written. Also a cron job to add group write permissions might do it.